# How to obfuscate all get communications with laravel obfuscate package in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, get, obfuscation

I made many routes in my laravel project. Now I have to obfuscate all the GET communications using laravel obfuscate package. How can I do this?

I tried to make global function to encode and decode get query string. encode function was used to obfuscate parameter in the href button of view and decode function was used to retrieve data. But I have to change all the codes related to each routing. I am tired of change all the code for many routes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.